# how to run a electron app without UI in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have already explored previous questions but they don't answer my question.
I have a simple Electron app with 2 inputs and a button. 2 inputs are multiplied and answer is shown in H1 tag.

[image]

I want to run this app in CLI without opening UI. I should be able to do something like this.

```
npm start myApp x,y
```

x and y are 2 inputs and this should print the result of multiplication

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with NPM scripts. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/introduction-to-npm-scripts-1dbb2ae01633/

[edit] Here's a very barebone app that to demo what you are looking for: [CLICK ME](https://repl.it/@LazaroFilm/WhichMonthlyHandwritingrecognition#myApp.js)
Read the noted in the myApp.js file to see it work.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, This is my day 1 with Electron and node etc. I can't understand NPM Scripts.

Comment: @shahidhamdam I've edited my answer with an small demo. I recommend you learn your way around NPM first though.